# How to remove extra space between rows in LaTex?

Tags: latex, tabular

There is extra space between the 1st and 2nd bullet points on the right column. How can I remove it? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX} \hline
Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence& $\bullet$ Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence \\
& $\bullet$ Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence \\
& $\bullet$ Example sentence \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image: f]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX} \hline
Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence& $\bullet$ Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence \newline
$\bullet$ Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence Example sentence
\newline $\bullet$ Example sentence \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What was the trick? Just replacing `\\ ` with `\newline`? Can you explain your answer a bit?